# Splitting a large dataset into smaller groups based on unique IDs

Tags: stata

I have a large dataset with ~ 600,000 observations. I need to split it into 20 groups of 30,000 each.

I do not have a classifying group like the [Stata FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/save-parts-of-dataset/) suggests, so using:

```
keep if group == `i'
```

would not work for me, I think.

My dataset looks like this:

```
ID       Company
1        Aat
2        Adt
3        Bat
4        Bjt
5        Coffee
.        .
.        .
.        .
600,500  Zyborgg
```

Currently, I am breaking it down using:

```
keep if id < 600000 & id >= 550000
```

However, it is time-consuming to do this 13 times for groups of 50,000.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a toy dataset with `600` artificially-generated observations:

```
clear
set obs 600

generate var = rnormal()
generate group = int((_n - 1) / 30) + 1
save data, replace
```

The following works for me:

```
forvalues i = 1 / 20 {
    use data if group == `i', clear
    save data`i', replace
}
```